# Removing a View in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, overlay

Hi trying to do something very simple in swift, graphically add a view to sit on my maiview story board, with a button that if clicked, it will remove the view from the scene. currently it removes everything and it goes black, subview and super maiView

so i have made another script which uses the tag attribute but it throws a error

```
@IBAction func removeView(sender: UIButton) {
    if view.tag == 99
    {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

saying the view is not NSCoding compliant.

the subview viewp does have a controller which inherits from UIView, goal is to make a tool tip to sit on the app when a user uses it to show them how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First You Have To Take Outlets For Both Views.

`@IBOutlet weak var currentView1: UIView!`

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentView2: UIView!
 var isFirstView:Bool = true {
 didSet{
if isFirstview {
 currentView1.removeFromSuperview()
   } else {
  currentView2.removeFromSuperview()
   }
  }
 }
```

> Handle Bool Variable in Button Action

```
@IBAction func onTapScan(sender: UIButton) {
isFirstView = !isFirstView
 //handle here depends on your Condition
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func removeView(sender: UIButton) {
    if view.tag == 99
    {
        view.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```